# Searching large data in mysql+PHP using Trie

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm having project that need seearch function, in large database. For example I would like to search keyword from 8000ish records. And the search will checking 7 fields for each records.
I would like to have relevancy search, which miss type can bring suggested result, like I search: blaeck, will bring result black (he intended to get this black result)

I was try to use Levenshtein, but its way too slow.
I was reading about PHPTrie, its implementing Trie using PHP. I did found code that do this too (https://github.com/fran6co/phptrie). I try this because I read that using Trie the time will be alot faster. But I'm not getting much more info and my PHP skill is not advance enough to create on my own. 
My question is, how to implement the trie? Is there any detail about it? In the class provided in that link above, it has search function, but not giving anything.

Or is there any other solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a search index like [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) for this. You can give entries in the index a "weight" in other words relevance. If you dont want to use a dedicated index DB you'll have to calculate the weight or relevance yourself and store it for each record.

Comment: Thank you! this indeed help me, but i cant use external db for this project. must only within my own db and i read, that in ES, we must put our keyword there, right? i cant do that sadly.

Comment: No, that's not how ES works. Read the manual. Like I said, if you can't use another DB you'll have toadd your own relevance calculation and store it with your data in the table and order by it.